# How to include everything before Colon in Sed/Grep/...?

Tags: sed, grep

Code

```
sed -n 's/.*tex:/[preventColonFromResult]/p' ./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?
```

where

- input is `./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?`.
- expected output is `./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex`.

I think `-n` does not make sense here because I want to pass the output to `less`. 
I search the match `.*tex:` but it actually should not include `:` in the result. 
I keep `p` at end to not do replacement.

### DonCristi's output for `grep`

Trying to split at colon `:` with `grep` without the seed of `sed`/`grep`/...
Code in GNU Grep 2.23

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec ggrep -i -oP '^[^:]*(?=:)' {} \; | less
```

Unsuccessful output with output as the content of files, not filenames. 
This command actually includes only content of files, and it leaves outside the filenames.

---

How can you get everything before colon `:` in SED/Grep/...?

Comment: I feel that this is grep's output. There are better solutions with just grep.

Comment: I cannot answer if I'm not sure. Is this grep output or not?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, it is. Particularly `find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -i -H "agent" {} \; `.

Comment: @don_crissti Can you get it work with the `find` command? Please, provide your output. My output in unsuccessful and many lines of `ggrep: agent: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @don_crissti Your command leaves filenames outside and includes filecontents. Expected output is filename without colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have taken the time and read the `grep` manual, you would have found the `l` option

```
-l, --files-with-matches
       Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which  output would normally
       have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.
```

Your `find` command would look like

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "agent" {} \; | less
```

or faster

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "agent" {} + | less
```

Answer (score 5):

1. **`sed` operates on stdin, not on its arguments**, unless you are giving it filenames.
2. It's easier to specify what you want to remove than what you want to keep, with `sed`.

Instead of

```
sed -n 's/.*tex:/[preventColonFromResult]/p' ./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?
```

perhaps you meant

```
printf '%s\n' './BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?' | sed 's/:.*//'
```

But for this specific use case, you may as well just use a single-purpose tool, namely `cut`:

```
printf '%s\n' './BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?' | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: I really like your `printf` instead of `echo`, and `cut` variant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on doing this in sed and matching on the `tex:` instead of just `:`, you can also try:

```
echo "./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?" | sed 's/\(^.*tex\):.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "bla-bla-bla:ololo-testo" |sed 's/:.*$//'  
bla-bla-bla
```

Comment: the `$` anchor in that sed statement isn't necessary -- `*` is greedy by default

Comment: @JeffSchaller, it makes a difference on inputs that contain invalid characters (which `.` won't match).

Comment: Or just `cut -d : -f 1`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what won't match . ?

Comment: I had to go look at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03 to see what I missed. "A <period> ( '.' ), when used outside a bracket expression, is a BRE that shall match any character in the supported character set except NUL." Is there an odd locale case to worry about?

Comment: In UTF-8 locales (the norm nowadays), `.` generally won't match characters in single-byte character sets whose value is above 127. é in UTF-8 is `c3 a9`, while it's `e9` in iso8859-1 (the most common western charset before utf-8 became popular). So if you have `Stéphane` written in the iso8859-1 character set and the current locale's charset is UTF-8, `.` won't match that `0xe9` byte in between the `t` and `p` as that doesn't form a valid character in UTF-8. So `s/:.*$//` on an input like `foo:St<0xe9>phane:C` will yield `foo:St<0xe9>phane:C` while `s/:.*//` will yield `foo<0xe9>phane:C`.

Comment: (that's something that you can generally ignore when the input is valid text, but worth mentioning once in a while).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ abc="./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?"
$ pqr=$(echo "$abc" | sed -e 's/:.*//')
$ echo $pqr
./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex
```

This works for me.

Comment: What is the value of `abc`?

Comment: I gave it a random string aabbccddee:123123abc to test it.

Comment: Tried it with the sample that the OP gave. It worked with that too.
'abc="./BitTorrentSync/Gyn/1.12.2015.tex:  Agents in young <40yr?"'

Comment: Please update your answer with such a random string , and with the actual output, that would make it IMO more complete and understandable.