# How to Execute !gvim current line in Viewer?

Tags: vim, xargs, less

### Code `find-xargs(less)-gvim`

```
%http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277889/16920
find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "agent" {} + | less -s -M +Gg
```

Output

```
./InfectiousDiseases/1.4.2016.tex
./InfectiousDiseases/2.11.2015.tex
./InfectiousDiseases/21.4.2016.tex
...
```

In less, command `!gvim`

- You se the current line number at the status bar at the bottom. It locates at the top of the window.
- Expected output is the file *./InfectiousDiseases/1.4.2016.tex* of the current line in a new window *gvim*.
- Current output is unsuccessful with empty file in vim.

Muru's proposal with Xargs in less

```
|X xargs gvim
```

which is about

> |Xcommand            Pipe file between current pos & mark X to shell
>   command.

...

### Muru's suggestion with `find-vim-gvim`

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "agent" {} + | vim -
```

I do successfully `:tabe <cfile>` or `:vs <cfile>` just by keeping cursor on the current line. 
I do successfully `!gvim <cfile>` but the list view goes to the another view `Press ENTER or type command to continue` which I do not like. 
I would like to keep the view in the list view. 
It would be also great to have a binding/macro for launching many external windows fast on the current line.

```
:nnoremap gff :silent! exec "!gvim " shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
```

which works successfully by pressing `gff` on the current cursor position. 
I think the sequence binding `gff` is too slow. 
It would be great to have a stereo binding that is pressing two buttons which activates the macro. 
I can recall that CTRL-1 or CTRL-ESC or CTRL-F1 could be possible.

...

I am having some problem with stereo keybindings `<C-1>` because stereo keybinding is impossible in Vim, but not in some Gvim's. I extended OS X specific part [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235623/15504) in Apple Stackexchange, but noticed that Vim Stackexchange knows better so [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7452/2923).

---

How can you execute gvim on the current line in viewer?

Comment: Yes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3saSk.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/FsObC.png

Comment: In less? Maybe try `|X xargs gvim`, where `X` is a mark (dunno what that is). In vim, maybe you could create a custom command: `:command E !gvim <cfile>`. Then you can do `:E`. (Or a map with similar effects)

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a typo, sorry about that.  For the status bar, that's the Vim Airline plugin: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline It's very popular.

Comment: Try this mapping: `:nnoremap gff :silent! exec "!gvim " shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>`. Then you can press `gff` while on the filename.

Comment: @muru I am thinking your `|X xargs gvim`. What do you mean by pipe here? Do you mean to start xargs inside less?

Comment: Yes. In `less` type `h`. You'll see `|X` mentioned right below `!`. It says it pipes content between current line and mark `X` to the command. And to convert stdin to args, `xargs` it is.

Comment: @muru Yes. However, I am not sure if it is `|X`. What about `+cmd`? That is `Execute the less cmd each time a new file is examined.` So if you examine new file each time from the list, execute `gvim`. Probably not.

Comment: @muru I am thinking the binding `gff`. I want it to be stereo that is pressing two buttons at the same time, not a sequence. I can recall that CTRL-1 or CTRL-ESC could be possible. How can you have a stereo binding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution to question [deprecated]

So first do

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec grep -il "agent" {} + | vim -
```

In .vimrc, one macro from vi.stackexchange where `gff` opens many windows of the visual selection

```
% https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7627/2923
if has("win32") || has("win64")
  :vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!START /B gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<cr>
else
  :vnoremap gff :<C-U>'<,'>g/^/silent! exec "!gnvim " . shellescape('<cfile>') . " &" <bar> redraw!<cr>
endif
```

Challenges

- even distribution of windows in OS X, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7637/2923; distribution works evenly in Ubuntu 16.04

### Much better solution

Use the proposal [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7787/2923) and just use tabs `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>gf :silent! execute "tabe " . expand('<cfile>') <bar> redraw!<CR>

function! OpenSelectionAsTabs() range
    let tabnr = tabpagenr()
    for line in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        execute "tabedit " . getline(line)
        execute "tabp"
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>gf :'<,'>call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
vnoremap <leader>gf :call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
```